# Trying the add to an array and calculate the average

Tags: javascript, arrays, average

First time poster.  I created 2 buttons, one to add a number to an array and another to calculate its average.  I can add a number but whenever I click the button to calculate the new average it gives me huge numbers.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Loops</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
            <script src="Java.js"></script>

        </head>
            <body onload="AddNumbers()">
            <header>

            <button onclick="PlusNumber()">Add Number!</button>
            <button onclick="GetAverage()">Get Average!</button>

            <p id="NumArray"></p>
            <p id="AvNum"></p>

                </header>           
    </body>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var array=[23,78,64,98,64,23,44];
var sum=0;

function AddNumbers(){
    document.getElementById('NumArray').innerHTML=array;
}
function PlusNumber(){
    var AddNum=prompt("Enter a Number");
    array[array.length]=AddNum;
    document.getElementById('NumArray').innerHTML=array;
}

function GetAverage(){
for(index=0;index<array.length;index++){
    sum+=array[index];
}
    var average=sum/array.length;
    document.getElementById('AvNum').innerHTML=average;

}
```

Comment: Move `var sum = 0;` to the start of the `GetAverage` function. As it is now, it never gets reset and just gets bigger every time the function is run.

Answer (score 2):

you need `parseInt` new entry if not it applies as string.

and initialize sum as 0 before calculate avarage in function

```js
var array=[23,78,64,98,64,23,44];
var sum=0;

function AddNumbers(){
    document.getElementById('NumArray').innerHTML=array;
}
function PlusNumber(){
    var AddNum=prompt("Enter a Number");
    array[array.length]=parseInt(AddNum);
    document.getElementById('NumArray').innerHTML=array;
}

function GetAverage(){
sum=0;
for(index=0;index<array.length;index++){
    sum+=array[index];
}
    var average=sum/array.length;
    document.getElementById('AvNum').innerHTML=average;

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Loops</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
            <script src="Java.js"></script>

        </head>
            <body onload="AddNumbers()">
            <header>

            <button onclick="PlusNumber()">Add Number!</button>
            <button onclick="GetAverage()">Get Average!</button>

            <p id="NumArray"></p>
            <p id="AvNum"></p>

                </header>           
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hey Thanks!  I've only started studying Javascript a couple weeks ago and had no idea that parseInt even existed, lol.